# Differentiation of complex vector matrix product

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

I am reading a paper and can't understand the following step.

Let $\Phi_j$ be a complex vector and $W$ a real symmetric, positive definite and block diagonal matrix. Both $\Phi_j$ and $W$ depend on some parameter $p$.
Let $(\cdot)^H$ denote the conjugate transpose of a vector and $\overline{(\cdot)}$ the conjugate.

By differentiating the equation $\Phi^H_jW\Phi_j$ w.r.t. $p$ the author derives the following equation:

$$\frac{d}{d p}(\Phi^H_jW\Phi_j) = \Phi^H_jW\frac{d\Phi_j }{d p}+ \overline{\Phi^H_jW\frac{d\Phi_j }{d p}}$$

Is this some sort of chain rule? Am I missing the obvious here?
Thanks

Comment: When in doubt, write everything doubt in coordinates and compute. (Bluntly: shut up and calculate!). In this case, $$\Phi^H W\Phi = \sum_{h, k} W_{h{}k}\Phi_h\overline{\Phi_k}.$$Compute the derivative using the rules of differentiation.

Comment: This yields the desired result only if $W$ does not depend on $p$, i.e. $\frac{dW}{dp}=0$. Otherwise I get the desired term $ + \Phi^H\frac{dW}{dp}\Phi$.

Comment: If $W$ depends on $p$ the result you found in the paper is wrong.

Comment: This solves it then. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome but I didn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that matrix-vector multiplication is essentially just summation and multiplication ;)